# Fscanf and delimiters

Tags: c, delimiter, scanf

I'm trying to read data from a file in C which will be always formatted in this types of lines:

```
16 Oct 2013 00:01:00.000,0.000,0.000000
```

This is a string, a comma, a float number, a comma, a float number, and a `\n`.

I was getting weird things, and I started trying with only strings, and I realized this:

```
fscanf(filefd, "\n%24[^,]s", data);
fscanf(filefd, ",%5s", data2);

fscanf(filefd, "\n%24[^,]s,", data);
fscanf(filefd, "%5s", data2);

fscanf(filefd, "\n%24[^,]s,%5s", data, data2);
```

Why the first case works and the other two don't? If I put the comma just before a variable, at the start of the format string, it works. If I put the comma in the other format string, but at the end, I get the comma in `data2`. And finally, if I put it all together, `data2` doesn't have any valid data, but `data` has.

Am I missing something to get this strange behavior?

Comment: Sergey, thank you for the corrections, I'm not native English, and I usually make mistakes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The corresponding argument type for `%[]` is already a string so the trailing `s` after the `]` is unrequired to indicate a string target, and is therefore expected to be present in the input stream. In all cases the input stops being consumed after the `]` because the `s` is not present, leaving the `,` in the input stream.

The first snippet works because it processes the `,` independently of the `]s`, the last two snippets do not and therefore fail because `s,` does not appear in the input stream.

Always check the return value of [`fscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) to determine the number of successful assignments made.

Comment: A simple extra s made me crazy yesterday. So simple, and now is working as perfectly as expected.